# Apple SignIn with Parse Server

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform, parse-server

My App is hosted on sashido.io, which offers Parse Server Hosting. Since it is required, I am trying to implement Apple SignIn for my app. As a first step, I've added the following code to my app. The Apple SignIn works, I get the token and the id, but I cannot create a Parse User with this data. This is my iOS-Code:

```
var authData = [String: String]()
authData["id"] = id
authData["token"] = token
PFUser.logInWithAuthType(inBackground: "apple", authData: authData).continueWith(block: {
    task -> Void in
       ...
})
```

I have verified that the authData contains the id and the token properly. Unfortunately, I get an internal server error as response `{"code":1,"message":"Internal server error."}`

After that, I have modified the following part of my index.js file like this and pushed it to sashido. Unfortunately, this didn't change anything and I'm still getting the internal server error.

```
var api = new ParseServer(
{
    databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
    appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',
    masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'masterKey',
    serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:' + port + '/1',

    // If you change the cloud/main.js to another path
    // it wouldn't work on SashiDo :( ... so Don't change this.
    cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || 'cloud/main.js',

    auth: {
       apple: {   
          client_id: process.env.IOS_BUNDLE_ID
       }
    },

    liveQuery: {
        classNames: []
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sign in with Apple support was initially released in Parse Server 3.5.0. However significant improvements and bug fixes have been made subsequently in 3.7.0, 3.8.0 and 4.2.0.

The latest version supported by Sashido is 3.6.0, however they haven't added support for Sign in with Apple yet. See the screenshot below from `app settings > users > social login` on 3.6.0...

[image: sashido dashboard screenshot]

Please also be aware that editing your `index.js` file and pushing it to your private Sashido GitHub repo will not change the Parse Server config. This facility is purely intended for local development use.

I would suggest you contact Sashido and ask them to add support for Sign in with Apple - ideally on Parse Server 4.2.0 this way you will get the latest improvements.

Comment: Thank you very much, also for the info regarding index.js. I have contacted sashido and will keep you updated here within this post

Comment: After contacting them, they setup apple sign in for me very quickly (and would setup any other authentication method supported by parse server). Now it works. Thanks Tom!